# How to create MAP property value in apache camel spring xml?

Tags: apache-camel

i'm using apache camel 2.16.08, In my  project need to send map of property value to the processor.i want create map in Spring Xml . Please help out of this.if you want more information let me know.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can see some examples:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/

Comment: this is not an answer to the question!!

Comment: The question was "how to create a map in spring XML". Provided link contains exact examples of that